# Disproving Zeno's paradox with straight edge and compass.

Tags: geometry

I can't shake the feeling there's a hole in this theorem attempting to disprove Zeno's contention that in order to move between two points, one would need to move between midpoint, and then through the midpoint between the start and the first midpoint in show on, taking an infinite number of steps, and therefore infinite time.

I'm familiar with disproving this using the principles of handling infinite series, but I wanted to try my hand with a geometric proof.

On a line L1, select points A and B. Construct a point C to the right of B a distance equal to half the distance between A and B. Then construct point D to the right of C a distance away half that between B and C. Note this can be continued indefinitely.

On a line L2, duplicate A,B,C,and D as A', B', C', and D'. To the left of A' construct point Z' a length along L2 equal to double the length of segment A'B'.

Note segment Z'A' is twice the length of segment AB, A'B' is twice the length of BC and so on. The parts being in a 2:1 ratio, the whole is in a two to one ratio. If we call the length of segments on L1 q, then the length of the segments on L2 is 2q.

2q being longer than q only by twice the length of segment AB, it follows that the length of q is twice the length of AB. So traversing the infinite collection of segments only takes twice as long as traversing AB, which is finite. So those infinite midpoints can be crossed in finite time.

Is there a flaw in the proof?

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: Zeno's paradox is obvious false so it isn't a question of showing that it *is* false.  The question is where is the error.  According to Zeno's paradox you haven't proven that the midpoints are finite-- you have proven that AB is infinite and will take an infinite time to traverse.  Which is obviously false.  So the *real* question is why is it false.  You haven't answered that.

Comment: Zeno's Paradox is only resolve by the idea of limits and an infinite number of steps.  A construction will always have a finite number of steps, so that it likely not the way to go about it.

Comment: On Zeno's paradoxes, you can read here how to explain them by non-standard analysis: http://norvaisa.lt/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/McLaughlin-Resolving-Zeno-Paradoxes.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement "$2q$ being longer than q only by twice the length of segment $AB$, it follows that the length of $q$ is twice the length of $AB$" is true only if $q$ is finite, which is what you want to prove.

Take for example $q=(1,+\infty)$ so that $2q=(2,+\infty)$. In this case $2q$ is longer than $q$ only by the segment $(1,2)$, but the length of $q$ is not $1$.

Comment: Interesting! I think you might have it. I see one difference, but I'm not sure if it matters.

Given  $q=(1,+\infty)$, I add $ (-2,1)$. The addition of that segment creates a segment of twice the length of q. But this still fails if we can't make a distinction between twice an infinite length and an infinite length plus a little bit.